# Hide show java script code not working in my custome post templete

Tags: javascript

```
function openProject(evt, projectName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(projectName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

It's working in first post but did not work in secound post.

Comment: are you loading the second post by AJAX?

Comment: yes i have load second post by ajax

Comment: you need to call the function after AJAX, which event handlers invoke this function?